# useEffect cleanup function Typescript error: not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-effect

I have this block of code that should do the following:

- Dispatch a thunk do load data after 1st render
- Dispatch an action to reset state as the cleanup function for that effect

Since `dispatch` and `slug` won't change during this component lifecycle, the cleanup will basically run after the component unmounts.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const slug = props.match.params.slug || "";

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(THUNKS.LOAD_DATA(slug));
  return () => { dispatch(ACTIONS.RESET_STATE()); };
},[dispatch,slug]);
```

Everything is working as expected. But I would like to write the cleanup function as:

```
return () => dispatch(ACTIONS.RESET_STATE());
```

I know that arrow functions add an implicit `return` statement if when I write it like that. So basically I'm returning the `dispatch()` call.

And because of this, Typescript complains with the following error msg:

> `Argument of type '() => () => { payload: undefined; type: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'.`

What I think is happening: `EffectCallback` is probably expecting `void` as the `return`, and suddenly I'm returning a `dispatch()` call.

Can I custom type the `EffectCallback` somehow to accept this return call and get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `dispatch` actually returns the action object so it's not a `void` function.  You want to just ignore the returned value.

I have a solution that might seem silly unless this is a pattern that you use a lot, because all we are doing is moving the curly braces to another place.  But potentially it's one place instead of many.

Instead of messing with typescript definitions, we can override `useDispatch` with our own custom version that actually doesn't return anything.

```
import { useDispatch as useRegularDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Action, AnyAction } from "redux";

export interface VoidDispatch<A extends Action = AnyAction> {
  <T extends A>(action: T): void;
}

export const useDispatch = <A extends Action = AnyAction>(): VoidDispatch<A> => {
  const regularDispatch = useRegularDispatch();

  return (action: A) => { regularDispatch(action); };
};
```

Then you can use `dispatch` in a `useEffect` cleanup without any issues.